# typeorm leftJoinAndSelect fail with camel case foreign key generated

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Hello I posted an issue related to typeorm, node.js and joins on github but nobody has responded me so far, so I'm just curious if anyone can help me here. I would be so grateful, because I tried everything and nothing has worked.

Basically everything works fine for me, I love the library because it's super powerful, but when it comes to joins it generates camel case foreign key name because originally it's `driver_id` and when I check the generated sql query the output contains `driverId` which I don't want and obviously it doesn't work. I don't see any error in my code, so maybe someone could spot one.

Here's the submitted issue on github and everything is explained there: [github typeorm issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8599)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `@JoinColumn()` decorator

change `TripDriversEntity` class like this

```js
@ManyToOne(() => DriverEntity, (driver: DriverEntity) => driver.trips)
@JoinColumn({name: OPTIONAL})
driver: DriverEntity
```